# guardar en cache consulta de graphql

Tags: graphql, pwa, service-workers

**Saludos**, tengo una consulta en graphql que devuelve un arreglo de objetos y quisiera que mi service worker la guarde en cache. Actualmente tengo esta configuración

```js
{
  urlPattern: /^https?:\/\/backenddwa.herokuapp.com\/graphql/,
  handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
  options: {
    cacheName: 'graphql',
    expiration: {
      maxEntries: 4,
      maxAgeSeconds: 25 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 25 days
    }
  }
},

{
  urlPattern: /^https?:\/\/backenddwa.herokuapp.com\/graphql\/.*/,
  handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
  options: {
    cacheName: 'graphql2',
    expiration: {
      maxEntries: 4,
      maxAgeSeconds: 25 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 25 days
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que  GraphQL utiliza por defecto `POST` para obtener datos del back-end. Esto imposibilita que se pueda hacer "caching" de las respuestas.

Tienes 2 opciones:

- Cambiar la arquitectura a que sea offline first. Puedes encontrar un blogpost que hablar sobre ellos acá
  https://codeburst.io/highly-functional-offline-applications-using-apollo-client-12885bd5f335
- O cambiar el backe-end para que utilize `GET` para que las respuestas puedan ser cacheadas. No te recomiendo esta opcion porque los URL pueden a llegar a ser muy largos y los navegadores tiene una limitante en al cantidad de caracteres que pueden tener un URL. Aquí te dejo otro post que te puede ser de ayuda.
  https://medium.com/@jono/cache-graphql-post-requests-with-service-worker-100a822a388a